# Windows how to use the right ctrl key as the left ctrl?

Tags: windows, keyboard, ctrl

I am wondering what should I do to let the windows system recognize the right ctrl as the left one, and the left ctrl as the right ctrl. I want to do this since my left little finger is really tired of pressing left ctrl.

I tried using an ergonomic keyboard but it does not help.

Thanks.

Comment: You should buy a BEPO keyboard, or hire someone.... But you'll become fat because typing is a kind of sport for fingers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of SharpKeys?

SharpKeys (ver. 3.5) is a very tiny Windows freeware that allows you to remap or even reassign computer keyboard keys in the couple of different ways we saw above. It does so by adding an entry to your computer’s registry. SharpKeys runs on Windows 7/Vista/XP/2000.

To start mapping an old key to a new custom one,

- run SharpKeys and click on the Add  button. The key mapping dialog opens up giving you a long list of key positions to pick from.
- You can also click on Type Key and manually select the key you want
  by pressing it on the keyboard.
- Next, click the Write to Registry button and a reboot for the changes
  to take effect notification will come up. After the reboot, your keys
  will stand remapped. You can go back to Edit  or Delete the mapping
  altogether.

Answer (score 2):

This question contains several methods which should allow you to achieve what you want:

https://superuser.com/questions/36920/how-can-i-remap-a-keyboard-key

That "Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4" looks like it could work, and it is released by Microsoft, so you need not trust an additional vendor with your highly sensitive keyboard input. I wouldn't recommend using Autohotkey at least, it seems to be overkill. If that re-mapper does what it's name suggests, it should be the perfect solution.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339

edit:

I am new here, but i think that superuser would generally be a better place to ask this question.